# PHP - Facebook API ask for permission

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to log a player into Facebook. I am using the Javascript SDK for logging a user in, and i copied the script directly from face books page:

**login page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '260828287441151',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

<a href="postface.php">Try to post</a>

</body>
</html>
```

What i want, is that when i press that link i go to another page, that should do some server-side programming with Facebook.

**postace.php**

```
    <?php
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_APP_SECRET');

    $helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
    try {
      $session = $helper->getSession();
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
      // When Facebook returns an error
      echo "Error 1: " . $ex;
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo "Error 2: " . $ex;
    }

    if ($session) {
      // Logged in
      echo "The user is logged in!!";
    } else
        echo "not working";

?>
```

However, the above doesn't work. The $session variable is just null? I don't get this, since Facebook says that you should use that exact script (which i copied from them as well) to verify login if you used javascript, which i did?

Any pointers on to what i did wrong? The login part on the javascript page works fine, and it says i am logged in. It is the server-side part on the other page that can't verify the user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that logging in using the JavaScript SDK saves the `access_token` to a cookie, while the Facebook PHP SDK is looking at the `session`, which doesn't know about the cookie.

You need to extract the `access_token` from `$_COOKIE` and then use it on the second page to create a session.

Comment: ahh ok i see. Any chance u can come with some example code? I have never worked with Facebook SDK's and i am a little stumbled, since their documentation is very vague at some points.